# How to order search results by relevance and another field in Lucene.net

Tags: .net, search, .net-3.5, lucene, lucene.net

I have a requirement to sort search results by relevance **and** another field.

I need to do something similar to this:

```
using Lucene.Net.Search;

SortField[] fields = new[] { SortField.SCORE, new SortField("customField") };
Sort sort = new Sort(fields);

IndexSearcher searcher = GetSearcher();
Hits = searcher.Search(query, sort);
```

Except, `SortField.SCORE` is an integer constant, not a `SortField`.

Lucene.net version 2.3.1.3.

Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found an answer to this:

```
SortField.FIELD_SCORE
```

Not sure how or why I missed this...

Comment: Can you write more informations about how to implement your solution?

Comment: Same code as in the question, but change `SortField.SCORE` to `SortField.FIELD_SCORE`.